# How to count the number of rows matching certain values?

Tags: mysql, sql

Actually I have a table now:

```
[Person Table]:
ID  Name    age     City
====================================

1   Jack    14    New York
2   Mike    15    LA
3   Ben     16    Beijing
?           
100 Lee     32    Singapore

(total record = 100)
(Id is Primary Key)
```

Please provide a SQL script to query customer that his/her city occurs in the table more than or equal to 6.

Example:

```
The number of customer that live in New York is 10
The number of customer that live in LA=5 
The number of customer that live in Beijing=6.
```

So in this example the output should be all customer that live in New York and Beijing only.

Comment: Use `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY` to get the count of people in each city.

Comment: Have you tried any queries for yourself so far?

Comment: I tried but there is something wrong maybe. select * from Person where (select count(*) from Person group by City)>6

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
select * from customers 
  join (select city from customers group by city having count(*) >= 6) 
    as city_count
    on customers.city = city_count.city;
```

All you are doing is creating a list of the cities that have six or more customers and then using that to filter the original customers table.

[Link to SQL Fiddle - using 2 as the threshold](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0345/1)